# How to change format of the MySQL result?

Tags: mysql

I have a complex mysql query language, including several sub queries and my final result is as below. There is something that I am dealing with it and I can't solve it and this is a way result is being presented. I am wondering to know how can i change the structure of the result in a way that the result is being presented only in one row and I don't want to see NULL fields. I mean something like below

[image]

[image]

This is mysql query

```
select count(*) as userRetentionSameDay, null as 'userRetentionDiffDay' from (SELECT date(`timestamp`), `user_xmpp_login` 
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(`timestamp` ) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) as res1
right join (select date(ts), user
from table2
WHERE DATE(ts ) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
and product_id REGEXP ("^(europe+$" )) as lej1
on lej1.user = res1.`user_xmpp_login`
where res1.`user_xmpp_login` IS not NULL 
union all
select null as 'userRetentionSameDay', count(*) as userRetentionDiffDay from (SELECT date(`timestamp`), `user_xmpp_login` 
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(`timestamp` ) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) as res1
right join (select date(ts), user
from table2
WHERE DATE(ts ) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
and product_id REGEXP ("^(europe+$" )) as lej2
on lej2.user = res1.`user_xmpp_login`
where res1.`user_xmpp_login` IS NULL;
```

What are the recommended solutions to doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

SELECT A.userRetentionSameDay,B.userRetentionDiffDay FROM (

SELECT COUNT(*) AS userRetentionSameDay FROM 
(
SELECT DATE(`timestamp`), `user_xmpp_login` 
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(`timestamp` ) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS res1
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DATE(ts), USER
FROM table2
WHERE DATE(ts ) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND product_id REGEXP ("^(europe+$" )) AS lej1
ON lej1.user = res1.`user_xmpp_login`
WHERE res1.`user_xmpp_login` IS NOT NULL 
) A,
(
SELECT COUNT(*) AS userRetentionDiffDay FROM (

SELECT DATE(`timestamp`), `user_xmpp_login` 
FROM table1
WHERE DATE(`timestamp` ) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY

) AS res1

RIGHT JOIN (SELECT DATE(ts), USER
FROM table2
WHERE DATE(ts ) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND product_id REGEXP ("^(europe+$" )

) AS lej2
ON lej2.user = res1.`user_xmpp_login`
WHERE res1.`user_xmpp_login` IS NULL

) B;

Comment: Thank you, it works, can you explain it a little bit also if you can explain my problem?

Comment: Union only adds the rows not the columns so if want two columns from same data use the aliasname for the each result and then perform select from it.

Comment: Joins can also be used in above query but we have to make different alias names for same table.

Comment: ok, query need 16 s to run, do u think query in general is ok in terms of performance? I mean it seems that the solution only is subquery?